# Java method parameter to represent different types

Tags: java, generics, parameters, class-method

Is there a way for a java method to accept parameters of different types?

```
public class Test {
  public boolean isTest(Type1 type1) {
    do_something_with_type1
    return bool;
  }

  public boolean isTest(DifferentType2 type2) {
    do_something_with_type2
    return bool;
  }
}
```

In this case the `do_something_with_X` part is common between two methods. To avoid the duplicate part, we should have something like:

```
public class Test {
  public boolean isTest(Object obj) {
    do_something_with_obj
    return bool;
  }
}
```

Can we do this in Java?

Comment: Well you can certainly write a method with an `Object` parameter, yes. Whether that's actually appropriate or not is a different matter - and one we can't tell without more context.

Comment: It kind of sounds like you want your method to accept _only_ those two types, but to have that implementation in common.  Is that correct?

Comment: It will depend on what "do_something_with_X" is doing. You could still extract "do_something_with_X" to a private function receiving an object as parameter and keep the original typing on the isTest functions.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this in too many ways. Beginning from the example you mention, using `Object` to generic management as the `List<?>` class does.

Java generics can work in too many ways, defining themselves at a class level, at a method, or even on a method parameter.

## Generic definition at a class level

```java
class Example<T> {
   public void foo(T type) {}
}

void usage() {
    Example<String> example = new Example<>();
    example.foo("Accepts strings");
}
```

## Generic definition at method class level

```java
class Example {
   public <T> void foo(T type) {}
}

void usage() {
    Example example = new Example();
    example.foo("Accepts anything");
}
```

## More complex generics

You can also specify rules to make your generic more strict. As for example, being a child or parent class of something.

```java
public <T extends List> void foo(T type) {}
```

or

```java
public <T extends Class<? super List>> void foo(T type) {}
```

or even further away, you can specify your generic to extend more than one class type:

```java
public <T extends List & AutoCloseable> void foo(T type) {}
```

or even more more more further away, you can specify the return type of your method based on the generic of a parameter of the method.

```java
public <R, T extends AutoCloseable & List<R>> R foo(T type) {
    return null;
}
void usage() {
    // Non existing class that implements AutoCloseable, List<T>
    AutoCloseableArrayList<String> list;

    // foo(T) will return String cause it's the generic of the parameter list
    String s = foo(list);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an interface with methods required to "do_something_with_obj" and implement the interface in type1 and type2. Then you can pass the object as interface.

Answer (score 0):

It is really hard to say without knowledge about do_something_with_x. I would suggest to extract do_something_with_x so your could keep the original typing on the isTest methods:

```
public class Test {
  public boolean isTest(Type1 type1) {
    doSomethingWithObject(type1);
    return bool;
  }

  public boolean isTest(DifferentType2 type2) {
    doSomethingWithObject(type2);
    return bool;
  }

  private doSomethingWithObj(Object object) {
      //do_something_with_object
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Well, you can use generics probably

```
public class Test {
  public <T> boolean isTest(T obj) {
    do_something_with_obj
    return bool;
  }
}
```

Accepting an `Object` as parameter is pretty unusual and not always the best choice... you might want to have a look at polymorphism if you can edit those 2 types you care about (defining an interface with the methods you care, and let those 2 classes implements that interface)

Or if you can't, you might want to take a look at the Adapter design pattern, but it's a bit overkill if you need this only one time

Comment: This is a really bad answer. It's `public boolean isTest(Object obj)`, but written in an obtuse, hard to read manner. Do not do this. Do not write your code like this. Remember with generics: If you declare a typevar and use it in one place you've messed up.

Comment: @rzwitserloot yes sure, generics are the same as `Object`... WHAT?!  let's say that `do_something_with_obj` is `param.callMethodA()`...  `Object` no more works... or let's say you want to pass that parameter to another method (that requires a specific type)... `Object` does not work anymore... great comment, YYYYUP

Comment: This code can be invoked with an Integer, a String, anything you want. There is nothing you can invoke on `obj` unless you cast it, or it's a method that's in `j.l.Object`. When you have a typevar with no bounds and you use it once, it _IS_ the same as object. Read up / experiment some, perhaps, before putting forth such disasters in SO answers.

Answer (score -1):

Not directly.

You can make an `isTest(Object)` method but then it would accept all objects, from `Integer` to `String` to `Type1` to `Type2`. So that's a crap option, don't take that one.

But there are plenty of alternative options:

### Interfaces

If the `isTest` operation makes sense on `Type1` and `Type2`, and there is shared code between the two takes on isTest, but there is **no relationship** between `Type1` and `Type2` (no shared supertype), that feels like you messed up your API designs. Why don't Type1 and Type2 share an interface or (abstract) class?

Note that starting with JDK16 you can 'seal' interfaces, meaning, in the interface you enumerate which implementations of this interface exist, and no other code is allowed to implement it. Meaning, you know, for sure, at compile time.

Thus, you can make an interface and seal it so only `Type1` and `Type2` can implement it, and now you can be sure, and make `isTest(ThatSharedInterface)`.

### Helper methods

Just make your separate 2 `isTest` methods, and put the shared code in a helper. This can be as simple as:

```
public boolean isTest(Type1 type1) {
    return isTest0(type1);
}
public boolean isTest(Type2 type2) {
    return isTest0(type2);
}
private boolean isTest0(Object o) {
    ...
}
```

This uses two aspects:

- In general, the concept of public wrappers that hook through to an actual implementation that is private, as well as the concept of helper methods, tends to (by convention) use `0` as marker, which is used here.
- Because the isTest(Object) method is `private`, the fact that API-wise it's a disaster that allows any type, is not a problem. It's private: You know what you call it with.